# Rendering Complex SKSpriteNode to Reduce Performance Penalty

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, graphics, sprite-kit

I've written a simple game with a graphics engine that draws random planets in Swift/SpriteKit. It works well and has a colour generation system that is used to colour a randomly selected number of transparent PNG graphics which are aligned to create a composite image. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnJ5j.jpg

The number of PNG graphics it used varies but is usually 6 - 12. There are only about 12 PNG files used for the entire engine which are mostly about 400 x 400 pixels at 3x with smaller versions of the same. It can produce billions of wildly varied results which are sometimes quite pretty, so its quite economical, but there's a big problem.

The graphic is really just for eye candy but the framerate of the simple game they are for plummets *drastically* when a single planet is put on screen, especially when it is at a large size. I'm talking about a drop from 30 fps to 10 or even 5 if it is drawn at a large size like 400%.

I think its because the multiple levels of transparent bitmaps are creating a lot of work for the graphics of the SpriteKit. The separate PNG sprites do not need to be moved independently once the planet is drawn so I'd like to be able to flatten the graphics into a single bitmap so that I can get the same result without the performance hit. I'm using the Simulator app to run the game.

The graphic is a SKNode container that has multiple SKSpriteNodes added by a Planet class:

```
//container node
let planet = SKNode()
//sprite node with graphic loaded via an array of filenames
let graphicNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: pngGraphics[n])
//colours, scales and rotates graphic randomly
graphicNode.color = getColourObject(27, alpha: 0.7)
graphicNode.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
graphicNode.zRotation = rotation
graphicNode.setScale = pScale
//adds graphic to parent node
planet.addChild(graphicNode)
//repeat 6 to 12 times
```

The resultant planet SKNode I'd like to render with something like:

planet.flattenToBitmap()

Does anyone know if this is possible or there is another way to avoid the performance problems?

Many thanks,

Kwangle

Comment: It’s worth noting that the simulator’s rendering performance when using OpenGL (or frameworks that use it, like SpriteKit) is often dramatically worse than an actual iOS device’s would be. You might want to try running your app on a device to check whether this is going to be a real issue.

Comment: Simulator results are irrelevant. Also try to use atlases. SpriteKit is capable to render hundreds of nodes in a single draw pass at 60 fps if done correctly.

Comment: Thanks, all good points.

Comment: THOUSANDS of nodes... on last gen and current gen hardware.

Comment: thousands of nodes.... confised has a project easily pushing 2000 on ipad pro

Comment: I found a simple fix for this - simply render the collected node as a SKTexture:  
                let myTexture = SKView().textureFromNode(myNode)